# Проблема с чатом в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Данный код выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Как решить проблему?

```
import socket
from tkinter import *

tk=Tk()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 11719))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

text=StringVar()
name=StringVar()
name.set('cragum')
text.set('')
tk.title('Chat')
tk.geometry('400x300')

log = Text(tk)
nick = Entry(tk, textvariable=name)
msg = Entry(tk, textvariable=text)
msg.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
nick.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
log.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='true')

def loopproc():
    log.see(END)
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        message = s.recv(128)
        log.insert(END, message+'\n')
    except:
        tk.after(1, loopproc)
        return
    tk.after(1, loopproc)
    return
def sendproc(event):
    sock.send(name.get()+':'+text.get(),('255.255.255.255', 11719))
    text.set('')

msg.bind('<Return>',sendproc)

msg.focus_set()

tk.after(1, loopproc)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Приложите к вопросу стек ошибки (кнопка `править`), а то непонятно в какой строке это произошло, а угадывать -- время терять :) А так, я предполагаю что проблема в `sock.send(name.get()+':'+text.get(),('255.255.255.255', 11719))`, т.к. нужно будет в сокетах передавать байты, а не строку: `sock.send(bytes(name.get()+':'+text.get(), encoding='utf-8'),('255.255.255.255', 11719))`. Тоже самое касается и при получении из сокета -- придут байты и нужно будет в строку привести

Comment: А как привести обратно в строку?

Comment: Попробуйте: `str(s.recv(128), encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку - TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple).

Comment: На какой строке ошибка?

Comment: line 40, in sendproc
    sock.send(bytes(name.get()+':'+text.get(), encoding='utf-8'),('255.255.255.255', 11719))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
В той, что вы мне дали.

Comment: Ошибка из-за второго параметра, что у вас уже был -- `,('255.255.255.255', 11719)`, там написано что нужно число, а передается кортеж. Судя по описанию метода https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send там вторым параметром ожидается флаг